# Write to Application EventLog in C#

Tags: c#, event-viewer

I would like to write a custom source in the Event Viewer, for a number of different events.

I'd like to have the log name to just be "Application" and source to be "DDG ServiceWare".
I looked at the documentation on MSDN and made this:

```
    private static void _writeToApplicationEventLog(string logMessage, int eventID)
    {
        if(!EventLog.SourceExists("DDG ServiceWare"))
        {
            EventSourceCreationData exitEvents = new EventSourceCreationData("DDG ServiceWare", "Application");
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(exitEvents);
        }

        using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
        {
            eventLog.Source = "DDG ServiceWare";
            eventLog.WriteEntry(logMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error, eventID);
        }
    }
```

However, when I run it I get an exception saying:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll
The source 'DDG ServiceWare' is not registered in log 'Application'. (It is registered in log 'DDG ServiceWare'.) " The Source and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.*

It doesn't change even if I change `EventSourceCreationData exitEvents = new EventSourceCreationData("DDG ServiceWare", "Application");` to `EventSourceCreationData exitEvents = new EventSourceCreationData("DDG ServiceWare", "DDG ServiceWare");`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For which line does the Exception occur?

Comment: In the Example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#examples they quit the application after creating the source _"to allow it to be registered."_

Comment: It also says: _"An event log source should not be created and immediately used. There is a latency time to enable the source, it should be created prior to executing the application that uses the source. Execute this sample a second time to use the new source."_

Comment: @Fildor it happens in the last line `eventLog.WriteEntry(logMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error, eventID);`. So does this mean I should create the event log source on a different thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created example for you

```
void Main()
{
    _writeToApplicationEventLog("test", 123, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    _writeToApplicationEventLog("test", 123, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
    _writeToApplicationEventLog("test", 123, EventLogEntryType.Information);
}

private static void _writeToApplicationEventLog(string logMessage, int eventID, EventLogEntryType logType)
{
    string sourceName = "SampleApplicationSource";
    string myLogName = "myNewLog";
    string messageFile = "customlog.log";
    
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sourceName))
    {
        EventSourceCreationData mySourceData = new EventSourceCreationData(sourceName, myLogName);
        mySourceData.MessageResourceFile = messageFile;
        mySourceData.CategoryResourceFile = messageFile;
        mySourceData.CategoryCount = 1;
        mySourceData.ParameterResourceFile = messageFile;
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(mySourceData);
    }

    myLogName = EventLog.LogNameFromSourceName(sourceName,".");

    using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(myLogName, ".", sourceName))
    {
        eventLog.Source = sourceName;
        eventLog.WriteEntry(logMessage, logType, eventID);
    }

    
}
```

the log created under Applications and Services under name myNewLog
[image]

Comment: Trying to implement your code gave me 2 errors in the EventViewer. Event 1001 Windows Error Reporting. Event 1000 Application Error

Comment: please read this article . might help https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/working-with-eventviewer-using-C-Sharp-for-beginners/

Comment: @wads You tried it as administrator? Simple users aren't allowed to create event sources.

Comment: @Ralf I am local admin on the computer and my Visual Studio is opened as administrator.

Comment: @PowerMouse I tried the different scenarios in the link you send, but unfortunately it didn't write anything in the Event viewer. I'm wondering if it's something local on my machine that makes it not working - so I will test it on a different machine

Comment: I did test this on a different machine with both my own account (admin account) and a normal user account - it works perfectly on the machine on both accounts. It seems like there's something on my own computer, that makes it so it cannot. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a package like SeriLog which will make logging much easier (not just to event logs but to files and other destinations). Have a look at this https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events

Comment: I've saved the link and will definitely try to use this in one of my other projects. However, I would like to use the way that I've written, as it's only 4-5 events I need to write. Do you have any idea of how I can make it work?